# Can I set this.customTagPaths inside of onApplicationStart()?

Tags: coldfusion

I'm trying to set the this.customTagPaths variable on application.cfc dynamically, based on a value set on a config page. This is because the customTagPaths are different on my dev than they are on the live site, and I don't want to have to change the value every time I deploy to the live site. I can't set the custom tag paths via CF admin on the live site, either, because I don't control the live CF server. I'm finding that the value isn't recognized if I set it inside of onApplicationStart():

```
<cffunction name="OnApplicationStart"...

    <!---application.customTagPaths is set on the config page. On dev, this value is "C:/Inetpub/wwwroot/mySite/components/"--->
    <cfinclude template = config/appsettings.cfm">
    <cfset this.customTagPaths = application.customTagPaths>
```

With the above code, I get a "cannot find component" error when I try to instantiate an object on a cfm page:

```
<cfset session.user = createObject("component", "user").init()>
```

So I suppose the answer to my question is "no". And I imagine the reason for this is that the "this" scope inside of onApplicationStart() is local to the function, and not the same as the "this" scope which is used to set this.name and this.applicationTimeout and such. I could do my cfinclude of appsettings.cfm at the top of the application.cfc page, and set this.customTagPaths below it:

```
<cfcomponent>
     <cfinclude template="config/appsettings.cfm">
     <cfset this.Name="myApp">
     <cfset this.customTagPaths = application.customTagPaths>
     ...
```

And that works, but is this ideal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your initial question is no, as you found out.
The answer to your latter question is yes, that is exactly how you are supposed to do it. Except you will not use the Application scope reference. These application *settings* are not really stored in the Application scope.

And for others who may stumble upon this question in order to use per-application settings in the Application.cfc file you must first enable per-application settings on the Settings page of the ColdFusion Administrator. You then set the mappings or custom tag paths in the Application.cfc file as noted below.

[Documentation reference for specifying settings per application](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec0b63c-7fd5.html#WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec0b63c-7fdd)

> Custom Tags in per-application settings override those defined in the ColdFusion Administrator. For example, if you have two custom tags of the same name and they are in different locations in the Administrator and per-application settings, the one in the per-application settings is taken first.
>
> Note: Per-application settings are supported in applications that use an Application.cfc file only, not in applications that use an Application.cfm file. The per-application settings do not work if you have disabled application variables in the Memory Variables page of the Administrator.
>
> **Set the custom tag paths per application**
>
> 1. Check the Enable Per App Settings option on the Settings page of the ColdFusion Administrator.
> 2. Include code like the following in your Application.cfc file:
>
> `<cfset customtagpaths = "c:\mapped1,c:\mapped2">`
>   `<cfset customtagpaths = ListAppend(customtagpaths,"c:\mapped3")>`
>   `<cfset This.customtagpaths = customtagpaths>`

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I see what the problem was. In my onRequestStart() function, I have an if block for resetting the app:

```
<cffunction name="OnRequestStart" access="public" returntype="boolean" output="false" hint="Fires at first part of page processing.">
        <cfargument name="template" type="string" required="true" />

        <cfsetting requesttimeout="20" showdebugoutput="#THIS.showDebug#" enablecfoutputonly="false" />
        <cfset request.dsn = application.dsn>

        <!---ability to restart app without restarting the CF server--->

        <cfif THIS.mode EQ "dev" AND structKeyExists(url, "$$resetApp$$") AND url.$$resetapp$$ EQ 1>
            <cfset structClear(application)>
            <cfset structClear(this)>
            <cfset onApplicationStart()>
        </cfif>
```

The this scope vars I set are available before that if block, but because I'm clearing out the this and application scopes, those vars are wiped and unavailable after the if block. So what I did was this:
1. Place my cfinclude of the config file at the top of the page.
2. Set my "this" vars inside of that file. Since it's an include, it's essentially the same as if its code were there on application.cfc, so no need to set any application scope vars inside of it. This takes care of my customTagPaths problem.
3. Anything I want to use site wide from the this scope (such as this.dsn), save as an application scope var at the top of the page. 
4. In onRequestStart(), refer to this.showDebug and application.dsn before the if block that will clear out the this and application scopes.

Intuitively, I'd prefer to set this.customTagPaths inside of onApplicationStart(), so it's set only once (when the app starts), but that doesn't work; apparently, the function fires before any of the THIS scope vars at the top of the page have been set.

Comment: To clarify, I'm talking about 2 different issues. The solution to the customTagPaths problem is as Miguel said -- put my config file at the top of the page, setting whatever this scope variables I need to inside of it. My other problem had to do with this scope and application scope variables being cleared in onRequestStart().

Comment: OK dude, raise another question then. This is a Q&A site (so one Q, possibly multiple As), not a discussion forum. If you need to cross reference back to this question for context, that's cool.